# "Use Cellular Data" switch in the app settings

Tags: ios, appsettings

My app uses iCloud for syncing data. So it might needs to toggle cellular data ON and OFF in a device's settings.

I thought that these settings will be added automatically, but now the app has an empty settings view.

What I need to do for adding these settings?

Comment: The "Use Cellular Data" option automatically shows up in the settings for an app after the first time it actually uses cellular data to access the network.

Comment: Yes, but I've just checked this by syncing via iCloud through 3G. Still no option

Comment: I just verified what I stated. I had an app that didn't show the option in Settings. I then turned off WiFi on my iPhone and ran the app and did a network access. I then went back to the Settings app and the "Use Cellular Data" option appeared.

Comment: So, where is the problem? I've turned off WiFi on my iPhone then made some data in my iPad.The App in the iPhone shows me an alert, that the iCloud has an updated data. Then I've loaded these data. I've made some updates from the iPhone to the iPad. Synchronization works fine. There is no option at all.

Comment: You have iOS 8 on your iPhone, right? If so, I don't know why you aren't seeing the option.

Comment: Yes. I've had some problems with the iCloud in my iPhone after updating to iOS8. So, maybe I need to reset the iPhone. Anyway, thanks for Your comments.